# How to check if dataframe column contains multiple sets of strings and output a row for each set it contains

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes - 1 data table, and another for topics like this

```
df_Data = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['123','456','789','100','200'],
                    'Names':['the dog is Red and blue','Cat is Pink','animal is cyan','pet is BLUE','i am green']})

df_Topics = pd.DataFrame({'Blue':['blue','cyan','aqua'],
                    'Red':['red','pinnk','fuscia','crimson']})
```

I'm looking to use the Topic list to lookup if any of those keywords are in the df_Data, then create a new table with which topics were found in the Data like this:

```
ID   Topics
123   Blue
123   Red
456   Red
789   Blue
100   Blue
```

Comment: Your second dataframe is not reproducible. Can you test and fix the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `extract` all the keywords in your `Names` column using a regex expression, and then `map` back to the main color. By that you need a different data structure of `df_topics`, which fits better as a `dict`:

```
df_Topics = {'Blue': ['blue','cyan','aqua'], 'Red': ['red','pink','fuscia','crimson']}

s = {color: k for k, v in df_Topics.items() for color in v}

print (s)

{'blue': 'Blue', 'cyan': 'Blue', 'aqua': 'Blue', 'red': 'Red', 'pink': 'Red', 'fuscia': 'Red', 'crimson': 'Red'}
```

Now use `str.extractall` to get all the keywords, assign back to a column and finally `map` back:

```
df_Data = (df_Data.assign(Topics=df_Data["Names"].str.extractall(f'({"|".join(s)})', flags=re.I)
                          .groupby(level=0).agg(list)).explode("Topics"))

print (df_Data.assign(Topics=df_Data["Topics"].str.lower().map(s)))

    ID                    Names Topics
0  123  the dog is Red and blue    Red
0  123  the dog is Red and blue   Blue
1  456              Cat is Pink    Red
2  789           animal is cyan   Blue
3  100              pet is BLUE   Blue
4  200               i am green    NaN
```

Comment: Thanks, This works really well.  I am planning to start with a csv so am using this code to read the csv in with the format you start with:
reader = csv.DictReader(open(file_location_kw))

df_Topics = {}
for row in reader:
    for column, value in row.items():  # consider .iteritems() for Python 2
        if value !='': 
            df_Topics.setdefault(column, []).append(value)
print(df_Topics)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! This works really well. I am planning to start with a csv so am using this code to read the csv in with the format you start with:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(open('file.csv'))

df_Topics = {}
for row in reader:
    for column, value in row.items():  # consider .iteritems() for Python 2
        if value !='': 
            df_Topics.setdefault(column, []).append(value)
print(df_Topics)
```